# The farthest man-made object

Tags: solar-system, extra-solar-object

What is the man-made object which is currently the farthest from our planet?
Where is it in this very moment?

Comment: Are photons of modulated, radio frequency EM radiation considered "man-made objects"?

Comment: @User58220 You tell me. :)

Comment: Well is that would be acceptable, then it's still a dupe, only of [How big is Earth's sphere of broadcast influence?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/how-big-is-earths-sphere-of-broadcast-influence).