# What percent of star systems has planets that could potentially support life?

Tags: life

I wonder if there are any calculations that estimate the percentage of star systems with planets that potentially can support life?

Comment: Relevant? [The Drake equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation)

Comment: Have you done research on the Drake equation? I know it goes all the way out to communicating civilizations, but potentially life-supporting planets are part of the calculation. There is no brief answer to this question, as we are still relatively new at the game of finding planets.

Comment: As a point of reference, check out how many potentially habitable planets there could be just within 100 light-years of us: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/how-big-is-earths-sphere-of-broadcast-influence/4063#4063

Comment: Didn't Carl Sagan do something or present something on this?.. Yup, found this : http://mentalfloss.com/article/27835/carl-sagan-explains-drake-equation

Comment: @Dan Pichelman, I didn't know about it, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have a good estimate of this yet. Our ability to detect planets around other stars is very limited, and biased toward finding very large planets in very close orbits around stars.

Drake's [original estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation#Original_estimates) was that a star with planets would average between one and 5 planets capable of developing life, so the percentage would be quite high. [Other estimates range as low as ~40%.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation#Average_number_of_planets_per_star_having_planets_that_might_support_life.2C_ne)

Comment: And we don't know anything about the atmospheres of those planets, so their habitability isn't even a scientific question at the moment.